# Intel XDK: Is it possible to create a custom button for share sheet to upload images directly from camera roll?

Tags: android, ios, windows, intel-xdk

I use Intel XDK to create an app for iOS, Android and Windows. Is it possible create a button and create an extension that uploads an image or a video from the camera roll directly into my app?
Or it's necessary to do this in the native languages?

And if yes, how?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Comment: Thanks, wernersbacher, but I would like that when the user is in camera roll, he can share an image directly into my app, through the system share sheet. For that I need to create a custom app button that uploads the selected photo to my app's server.